# Any way to attach another mesh to another ( Not CTRL + J)

Tags: modeling

Basically, I'm creating a uniform, I want the uniform to have some pockets and the like[image]

I want to create nearly the same as in the picture, but I'm struggling at creating the pockets.
[image]

Imagine the cube is a pocket, how do I properly attach it and deform it so it perfectly attaches/merges to the jacket? It's hard to phrase, I hope you understand.

Comment: I think with the cube u make a pocket separate and with the shrinkwrap modifier u can stick to the uniform

Comment: Retopology techniques help a mesh to stick to the surface of an object as it is created. By having the mesh [snap to the surface](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html#transform-snapping) you can create the outline of the pocket to match the suit and then extrude it out.

Comment: Maybe it would help us if you could explain why it's a problem for the jacket and pocket to be a single object? Also, is it safe to assume the jacket and pocket should be able to deform together in animation?

Comment: I use often Parent ( constraint ) i.e. Ctl+p

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the Boolean modifier.  Select your jacket, add the modifier, change the mode to Union, and set the Object to the pocket cube.  Hit apply and it should make it one manifold mesh.

Answer (score 0):

To merge object you can use the *Join* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>J</kbd>) operation in *Object Mode*. Another way would be to go to edit mode and add another mesh primitive (<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd>), this creates an extension of the mesh you were working on in *Edit Mode*.

To create your pockets it might be advisable to create the pocket rather by face extrusion rather than adding a box.

Comment: Like I already stated in the question itself, just imagine the box is a pocket, I want to have the pocket be properly attached to the jacket. I stated aswell that I don't want to use CTRL + J.

Comment: Then you are left with adding (Shift + a in edit mode, then select mesh primitive). But there is - to my knowledge - no automated way to properly attach the box to your "jacket" mesh. You need to manually model your pocket afterwards by removing/adding/moving faces/edges/vertices in edit mode. I think there is no way around that. Maybe you could share your mesh, so we can help you a bit more "on target"?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the *Shrinkwarp* modifier on only the vertices that you want to attach and then blend the normals with the data transfer modifier. Like in this 8 Minute Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=luFz5gzvM9s&t=288s

It looks like one mesh if done well and it is nice to position anywhere you want on your jacket. You can also just duplicate the whole thing and you have a second pocket without any need for further modeling.